# Moving Sharepoint 2003 databases to a new SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

Recently we completed a new MSSQL cluster that we are planning on migrating all existing SQL databases to. This includes our Sharepoint databases, while looking into moving the databases I found the Microsoft documentation for moving Sharepoint 2007, however have not been able to find anything similar for Sharepoint 2003. Can anyone point me to a guide for moving the databases, or provide some tips, instructions or warnings? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the KB article that outlines the process:

[How to move the databases that are used by SharePoint Portal Server 2003 to a computer that is running SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894164)